Trouble Returning to Previous input in loop
I am creating a program that will have me enter 6 grades 1-50 and have it give me the total amount of points and the percentage of the scores. The only trouble I am having on it is that when the if loop activates, it will not return to the previous input and will skip to the next input. How do I make it so that it returns to the previous input so that it can be re-entered?
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
      int percent;
      int totalscore;
      const int score[5];
   for (int grades = 1; grades <= 6; grades++) { 
         printf("please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", grades);
         scanf("%d", &score[grades]);
   if (score > 0 , score > 51);
      printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 50\n");
      
   }
   totalscore = score[1] + score[2] + score[3] + score[4] + score[5] + score[6];
   printf("Over 6 assignments you earned %d points out of a possible 300 points!\n", totalscore); 
percent = totalscore / 3 ;
   printf("Your grade is %d percent.", percent);
   return 0;
   }



You're closing your if-statement immediately. Also, what are you trying to do with (score > 0 , score > 51)?

Read about Boolean operators.

An if statement is not a loop.  And please, please, please make your indentation consistent.  It makes it really hard to read the code when the indentation is as erratic as in the question at the moment.

You have const int score[5]; — how are you going to assign values to a constant array? You need to remove the const.  Also, how are you going to store 6 values in a array of 5 entries?  You should use 6 for the dimension.  In C, the array indices start at zero.  The idiomatic for loop would for (int grades = 0; grades < 6; grades++). Your post-loop processing should access score[0] and should not access score[6] — and could usefully be written as a loop.  You should use a named constant in place of 6 (e.g. enum { NUM_SCORES = 6 };) and use that in the array dimension and loops.

I can see some beginner's flaws in the input part itself.
The if condition is not correct. - you want to check the input value entered at a particular index, not the whole array. Also, you have closed the if condition by giving ; which breaks the scenario.
I have updated the code piece.
  for (int grades = 1; grades <= 6; grades++) {
    printf("please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", grades);
    scanf("%d", & score[grades]);

    // updated if condition. 
    if (score[grades] < 1 || score[grades] > 50) {
      printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 50\n");
      grades--;
    }

  }

EDIT -
updating the condition to accept inputs only from 1-50. Thanks @
Jonathan Leffler

There are some other problems — see my comment.  Your code allows the user to enter 0 which should be forbidden.

const int score[5]; ... const??? You should, at least, try to compile the code you post as an answer... This code does NOT even compile. (Let alone the UB of its treatment of the array...)

@Fe2O3 -- I am not sure which IDE/compiler you are using. The code is working fine on online compilers. Also, instead of downvoting in your ego, and giving useless comments, write down a better solution with a full explanation. It will help the beginners as well as the community in a better way. Thanks.

@ShikharGupta Hover your mouse/cursor over the DV button and read the text in the "tool tip" balloon. An "answer" that contains code that does not compile is not a useful answer. Rather than complaining, you have feedback and the opportunity to correct your answer.

In this code, you are making two mistakes.  The first is you are using a semicolon ';' at the end of the 'if' statement, and the second is that you have used ',' in the 'if' condition, which is not right.
You can see the correction below:-
if (score <= 0 || score >= 51)
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 50\n");


There are numerous other problems too — see my comment.

That is not a correct answer. by your solution, it is still hopping to the next input.

When I compile the code in the question (minimally reformatted), I get a lot of compiler warnings (and I tell the compiler to treat all warnings as errors):
clang -Wno-nullability-completeness -O3 -g -std=c18 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common ip83.c -o ip83
ip83.c:12:21: error: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'const int *' [-Werror,-Wformat]
        scanf("%d", &score[grades]);
               ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               %d
ip83.c:13:30: error: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('const int *' and 'int') [-Werror]
        if (score > 0, score > 51)
                       ~~~~~ ^ ~~
ip83.c:13:19: error: relational comparison result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-comparison]
        if (score > 0, score > 51)
            ~~~~~~^~~
ip83.c:17:62: error: array index 5 is past the end of the array (which contains 5 elements) [-Werror,-Warray-bounds]
    totalscore = score[1] + score[2] + score[3] + score[4] + score[5] + score[6];
                                                             ^     ~
ip83.c:8:5: note: array 'score' declared here
    const int score[5];
    ^
ip83.c:17:73: error: array index 6 is past the end of the array (which contains 5 elements) [-Werror,-Warray-bounds]
    totalscore = score[1] + score[2] + score[3] + score[4] + score[5] + score[6];
                                                                        ^     ~
ip83.c:8:5: note: array 'score' declared here
    const int score[5];
    ^
5 errors generated.

Most of the changes are discussed in my comment above (1).  Other answers correctly identified that this conditional is wrong on multiple counts: the comma operator is wholly inappropriate, and the comma after the close parenthesis is wrong.
if (score > 0 , score > 51);

One of the other answers correctly decrements grades so that you can re-enter a grade after a range error.  This code checks the return value from scanf(), and exits with a message written to stderr (not stdout) if it fails to read an integer.  It also counts the number of 'out of range' grades and exits if there are too many of them.  It uses enumeration constants for various limits, and calculates the total score with a loop.  You could change the code to accept 10 grades with values 0..100 by adjusting the enumeration constants.
Here is code that works sanely.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { NUM_GRADES = 6, MIN_SCORE = 1, MAX_SCORE = 50, MAX_FAILURES = 3 };

int main(void)
{
    int score[NUM_GRADES];
    int failures = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the grade for assignment #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &score[i]) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to read a grade - bailing out!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (score[i] < MIN_SCORE || score[i] > MAX_SCORE)
        {
            failures++;
            if (failures >= MAX_FAILURES)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "too many invalid grades - bailing out!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 50\n");
            i--;
        }
    }
    int totalscore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_GRADES; i++)
        totalscore += score[i];
    printf("Over %d assignments you earned %d points out of a possible %d points!\n",
           NUM_GRADES, totalscore, NUM_GRADES * MAX_SCORE);
    int percent = (100 * totalscore) / (NUM_GRADES * MAX_SCORE);
    printf("Your grade is %d percent.\n", percent);
    return 0;
}

Here's the output from a sample run:
Please enter the grade for assignment #1: 23
Please enter the grade for assignment #2: 13
Please enter the grade for assignment #3: 15
Please enter the grade for assignment #4: 19
Please enter the grade for assignment #5: 53
Please enter a number between 1 and 50
Please enter the grade for assignment #5: 50
Please enter the grade for assignment #6: 0
Please enter a number between 1 and 50
Please enter the grade for assignment #6: 1
Over 6 assignments you earned 121 points out of a possible 300 points!
Your grade is 40 percent.

